# Angular 5 ng-pick-datetime not clickable/working

Tags: angular, angular5

I have been checking all GitHub issues, forums and SO about this problem  for a while to no avail so I am making this new question.

We have a project that is built on Angular 5 and is still in production. However, in the new developer environments, we cannot make this work as taking this project over since it was last updated was last year, and Angular version is currently at 8, Angular 4 & 5 are no longer supported now.

Image below isn't clickable:

[image]

This is the note from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime#breaking-changes)

> The picker has been updated for Angular 6+ apps. If you are still using Angular 5, you should install the picker version 5.2.6. npm install ng-pick-datetime@5.2.6 --save

I've changed packages versions but still now working.  Tried down/upgrading the package and `typescript` version, `ng-pick-datetime-moment` to `1.0.5` or `1.0.6`.

This could probably caused by newer node/angular CLI or whatnot, but I am not sure.

Please suggest if you have any idea, been pulling my hair out of this. Kindly also point out what am I missing here. Thank you!

Comment: Can you create a minimal stackblitz ?

Comment: Hi @YogendraR, sorry not well-versed in JS/TS, just starting to work with this Angular project. Checked out stackblitz, and I don't know how I can make a new project with Angular 5.2, the Angular 8 is being created instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the error by adding the

`import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';`

```
imports: [
    OwlDateTimeModule, 
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule
],
```

on the modules that use it.